# Binary Search Tree _Deletion Node (Minimum Value of Right Subtree)

Tags: java, methods, binary-search-tree

I like to make a deletion method can delete the node and replace it with 
the minimum value of right sub-tree. I don't want to make setSrting method 
so I need to make an abject when I replace the value(min right sub-tree).
I tried `insert("b")`, `insert("d")`, `insert("c")`, `insert("a")` and `delete("b")`.
it delete `"c"` instead of `"b"`, I don't really understand why it works in that way. Please help me to fix the error of Delete method. Thank you.

```
class StringNode {

    private String word;

    private StringNode left, right;

    // constructor, setter for word
    public StringNode(String w) {
        word = w;
        left = right = null;
    }

    // getter for Left
    public StringNode getLeft() {
        return left;
    }

    // setter for Left
    public void setLeft(StringNode pt) {
        left = pt;
    }

    // getter for Right
    public StringNode getRight() {
        return right;
    }

    // setter for Right
    public void setRight(StringNode pt) {
        right = pt;
    }

    // getter for word
    public String getString() {
        return word;
    }

}

class BSTStrings {

    // member variable pointing to the root of the BST
    private StringNode root;

    // default constructor
    public BSTStrings() {
        root = null;
    }

    /*
    //copy constructor
    public BSTStrings(BSTStrings t) {
        root = copyTree(root); //"root = t" does not make a copy
    }

    //copy the base Node for root
    private static StringNode copyTree(StringNode l) {
        return l;
    }
    */

    // for output purposes -- override Object version
    public String toString() {
        return toString(root, 0);
    }

    private static String toString(StringNode l, int x) {
        String s = "";
        if (l == null)
            ;// nothing to output
        else {
            if (l.getLeft() != null) // don't output empty subtrees
                s = '(' + toString(l.getLeft(), x + 1) + ')';
            s = s + l.getString() + "-" + x;
            if (l.getRight() != null) // don't output empty subtrees
                s = s + '(' + toString(l.getRight(), x + 1) + ')';
        }
        return s;
    }

    /************************************************
     *
     * Search
     *
     *************************************************/

    // find the string
    public StringNode search(String s) {
        return search(root, s);
    }

    private StringNode search(StringNode x, String s) {

        // the comparison result define as an integer
        int cmp = s.compareTo(x.getString());

        // the desired string found
        if (cmp == 0)
            return x;
        // if the s lexicographically precedes root, search(lf subtree)
        else if (cmp < 0)
            return search(x.getLeft(), s);
        // if the s lexicographically follows root, search(rt subtree)
        else
            return search(x.getRight(), s);

    }

    /************************************************
     *
     * Insert
     *
     *************************************************/

    // insert s into this tree. If s is already in the tree, do nothing.
    public void insert(String s) {
        if (s == null)
            ;
        root = insert(root, s);
    }

    /*
     * inserts String value into binary search tree of which StringNode is the root
     */
    private StringNode insert(StringNode x, String s) {

        if (x == null) {
            // position if insertion found; insert after leaf
            // create new node
            x = new StringNode(s);
        } // end if
          // search for the insertion position
        int cmp = s.compareTo(x.getString());
        // search left tree
        if (cmp < 0)
            x.setLeft(insert(x.getLeft(), s));
        // doing nothing, if already there
        else if (cmp == 0)
            ;
        // search the right subtree
        else
            x.setRight(insert(x.getRight(), s));
        return x;
    }

    /************************************************
     *
     * Delete
     *
     *************************************************/

    // Deletes val from BST - does nothing if val is not in the tree.
    // Deletion must be done so that the replacement node is the smallest node
    // from the right subtree.
    public void delete(String val) {
        if (val == null)
            ;
        delete(root, val);
    }

    private StringNode delete(StringNode x, String val) {

        int cmp = val.compareTo(x.getString());
        if (x == null)
            ;
        else if (cmp < 0)
            x.setLeft(delete(x.getLeft(), val));
        else if (cmp > 0)
            x.setRight(delete(x.getRight(), val));
        else { // find it!
            if (x.getLeft() == null)
                return x.getRight();
            if (x.getRight() == null)
                return x.getLeft();
            StringNode t = x;
            // replace current node which need to delete
            // with min of right sub tree
            x = min(t.getRight());
            // delete the smallest value of right subtree
            x.setRight(deleteMin(t.getRight()));
            x.setLeft(t.getLeft());
        }
        return x;

    }

    // delete the smallest
    private StringNode deleteMin(StringNode x) {
        if (x.getLeft() == null)
            return x.getRight();
        x.setLeft(deleteMin(x.getLeft()));
        return x;
    }

    // returns smallest
    private StringNode min(StringNode x) {
        if (x.getLeft() == null)
            return x;
        else
            return min(x.getLeft());
    }

    /************************************************
     *
     * Height
     *
     *************************************************/
    // return height of the tree
    public int height() {
        return height(root);
    }

    private int height(StringNode x) {
        if (x == null)
            return -1;
        return 1 + Math.max(height(x.getLeft()), height(x.getRight()));
    }

    /************************************************
     *
     * Closeness
     *
     *************************************************/

}
```

Comment: So you want to end up with *two* nodes carrying the value that is initially the minimum of the right subtree?  Or are you really just asking what's wrong with your `delete()` method?

Comment: I don't really understand why you have a `deleteMin` method? Is this part of this question?

Comment: I use "deleteMin()" for making the rightsubtree without the minimum node, but if you have a better idea please feed back me :) Thanks

Comment: but I think I forget to ubdate "root" variable after I do delete method. So the public void delete(String val) {
        if (val == null;
        root = delete(root, val);
    }

Comment: In the event that the node containing the target string has no left child, you just move up its right child.  That preserves the BST structure, but if the deleted node has a (right,left) grandchild then the result is not the behavior you said you want.

Comment: after I changed it to root = delete(root, val); it works good now.. when I debugging my delete method has no problem, I just forget to put "root = "